# Resolve Linker Error

Tags: c++, linker-errors

I am getting a linker error when I try to call the insertionSort() class method. Why is this happening?

**The error**

```
     Error  3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol 
"public: static void __cdecl Guitar::insertionSort(class Guitar * const,int,int)" (?insertionSort@Guitar@@SAXQAV1@HH@Z) 
referenced in function _main  SortingDemo.obj   SortingDemo
```

**The code**

```
//Guitar.h
#include <string>

class Guitar
{

    void compareExchange(Guitar &a, Guitar &b);
    void exchange(Guitar &a, Guitar &b);

public:

    int yearMade;
    int value;
    std::string brand;
    std::string model;
    void static insertionSort(Guitar a[], int left, int right);

    Guitar::Guitar(): yearMade(0), value(0){}
    Guitar::Guitar(int year_made, int val, std::string brand_name, std::string model_name)
    {

        yearMade = year_made;
        value = val;
        brand = brand_name;
        model = model_name;
    }
};





//Guitar.cpp
#include "Guitar.h"
#include <string.h>
void exchange(Guitar &a, Guitar &b)
{
    Guitar temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}
void compareExchange(Guitar &a, Guitar &b)
{
    if (b.value < a.value)
        exchange(a, b);
}
void insertionSort(Guitar a[], int left, int right)
{
    int i;
    for (i = right; i > left; i--) compareExchange(a[i - 1], a[i]); // puts the lowest value in the array into array[0]
    int lowest = a[0].value;
    for (i = left + 2; i <= right; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        Guitar v = a[i];
        while (v.value < a[j - 1].value)
        {
            a[j] = a[j - 1];
            j--;
        }

        a[j] = v;
    }
}




//Main
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Guitar g1;
    g1.value = 150000;
    g1.yearMade = 1957;
    g1.model = "Strat";
    g1.brand = "Fender";


    Guitar g2;
    g2.value = 150;
    g2.yearMade = 2015;
    g2.model = "Squire";
    g2.brand = "Fender";


    Guitar g3;
    g3.value = 5000;
    g3.yearMade = 2015;
    g3.model = "Les Paul";
    g3.brand = "Gibson";


    Guitar gtr_guitar;
    Guitar gtrArr[] = { g1, g2, g3 };


    Guitar::insertionSort(g, 0, 2);

}
```

Comment: You didn't define `Guitar::insertionSort`. You only declared it.

Comment: `insertionSort` is a static member function of `Guitar` and needs to be qualified as such in the cpp. `void Guitar::insertionSort(Guitar a[], int left, int right)`

Comment: Your class methods are not named properly in the implementation either... they are lacking their namespace components.